# Confict with package named tensorflow in custom library Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, namespaces

I am developing a library in Python with the following package and modules hierarchy:

```
my_library/
    __init__.py
    ...
    tensorflow/
        __init__.py
        models/
            __init__.py
            classification.py
            segmentation.py
        losses.py
        ...
```

Both in `classification.py`, `segmentation.py` and `losses.py` I have the import:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

And in `losses.py` I have a function with the decorator: `@tf.function`

When I try to run my code I get the following error:

```
File "/home/me/Library/my_library/my_library/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from my_library.tensorflow.models import segmentation
  File "/home/me/Library/my_library/my_library/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import tensorflow
  File "/home/me/Library/my_library/my_library/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import models
  File "/home/me/Library/my_library/my_library/tensorflow/models/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import classification
  File "/home/me/Library/my_library/my_library/tensorflow/models/classification.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/me/Library/my_library/my_library/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import losses
  File "/home/me/Library/my_library/my_library/tensorflow/losses.py", line 11, in <module>
    @tf.function
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'function'
```

It seems that there is a conflict between names. If I change my `tensorflow` package name by another name, the problem dissapears, but I prefer to not change it (if possible). My `tensorflow` package is inside `my_library` scope. Why there is the conflict? Is there any way to fix it? Am I using the `import` statements wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You really should change the directory name. That would be the only "right" solution

Comment: Really? There is no solution to have a sub-package with the name `tensorflow`?

Comment: Even if there was, it would be wrong. Any other 3rd party package you may use in the future that might `import tensorflow` or something from it will get confused and import your tensorflow (because importing from current working dir has precedence over importing from `site-packages`)

Comment: Mmm.. there is no confusion to me. My `tensorflow` package is inside the `my_library` scope, so it is only accessible via `my_library.tensorflow`. Putting an alias is fine to distinguish them: `from my_library import tensorflow as ml_tf`

Comment: Again, the majority of the problem is not for your code. It's for other people's code. Just rename the directory. It will save you a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

To understand better on what you are truly dealing with, here is a helpful reference to the python module search path: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:
>
> - The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified).
> - PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).

The important part is "**The directory containing the input script**". It's the fact that the `test.py` script is in the same directory as the tensorflow directory that makes it visible to the import system.